# Coherence of a single function given a single frequency

Tags: coherence

I have a signal sampled from a hardware, `s`. I would like to compute the coherence of the sampled signal given a single frequency, `f`. Below are the approaches I can think of.

1. Base on `f` generate a synthetic signal and compute the coherence of `s` and the synthetic signal.
2. Use `SNR` similar approach with frequency range `[f - a, f + a]` to compute the `SNR` of `s` as its coherence level, where `a` is a threshold.

I know both approach are not the right way to do it. There are just the possible solutions come to my mind. I would like to know how to do it right.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "coherence given a single frequency"?

Comment: Sorry for not giving enough info. In matlab we can compute coherence of 2 signals with mscohere. However in my case I only have 1 signal, `s`. But I'm given a desired signal frequency `f` for ideal case. I would like to compute how close the signal `s` with the ideal case. Perhaps coherence is not the right word here.

Comment: What do you know about $s$? Is it a pure sinusoid?

Comment: `s` is not a pure sinusoid, it can be any signal polluted by noise. The objective is to compute the level of frequency `f` with a threshold, `a` in signal `s`. If all frequency in `s` fall into `[f - a, f + a]` then it should give 1.0